# Can't get_users info by using json_encode

Tags: php, functions, users, html, json

Here's the code that i used:

```
function get_users(){
   $all_users = get_users();

   $arr=array();

   foreach ($all_users as $val) {
       $arr[]=$val->data->user_nicename;
   }

   $resp = array (
       'data'       => json_encode($arr)
   );
   wp_send_json($resp);
}
```

this code is working like this:

```
["john","mark","mena"]
```

I want the code to work like this:

```
[{value: "user_nicename", label: "display_name",icon: "user_avatar"}]
```

Comment: This isn't a question about WordPress so much as vanilla PHP, and as such might be considered off-topic for our site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
function get_users(){
    $all_users = get_users();
    $arr=array();

    foreach ($all_users as $val) {
       $arr[]=array( 'value'=> $val->data->user_nicename, 'label'=> $val->data->display_name, 'icon' => get_avatar_url($val->ID));
    }
    wp_send_json($arr);
}
```